# Creating IaC with AWS CDK to just get the CloudFormation equivalent code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code, aws-devops

I'm working with a customer that wants all the IaC in CloudFormation. I'm not good at CloudFormation. I wonder if it is a common practice to create the IaC using AWS CDK, generate the CloudFormation equivalent, and use it?

Is this something that is commonly done ?

Comment: yep, the aws cdk synthesises the code into a cloudformation template in order to deploy, can handle outputs nested stacks maps, etc.

Comment: bye CloudFormation then

Comment: CDK is basically a dynamic wrapper around Cloudformation. Technically, you can generate the pure Cloudformation template for a given stack with something like `npx cdk synth` (in this case when using the JS/TS flavour). However, be aware that this Cloudformation output will be overly abstract as it has to make some assumptions in comparison to natively/hand-crafted Cloudformation. Anyway, if your client wants Cloudformation, CDK should be just fine, if not better.